# Menu's inks doesn't work if i use JQuery $(window).click(function() to close the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good evening everyone, I am creating a popup menu using jquery. This menu is opened using a button and closes when you click anywhere on the screen, my problem is that now every time you click on the screen the function start again, if I use `return false` the links in the menu do not work.
How can i resolve te problem???

this is my jquery code:

```
$('#menu-button').click(function() {
    $('#menu-button').css('left', '-130px');
    $('#header').animate({'top': '0px'}, 700);
    return false;
});

$(window).click(function(event) {
    $('#header').animate({'top': '-100px'}, 700);
    $('#menu-button').css({left: '5px'});
    return false
});
```

this is the html :

```
<nav id="header">
    <a href="page1.html"  title="">1</a></li>
    <a href="page2.html"  title="">2</a></li>
    <a href="page3.html"  title="">3</a></li>
</nav> <!-- header ends here -->
<a href="" id="menu-button">Menu</a>
```

this is the css :

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 10;
}

#menu-button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    .cerchio;
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    .box-shadow;
    z-index: 10;
    .transistion;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling

```
$('#menu-button').click(function() {
    $('#menu-button').css('left', '-130px');
    $('#header').animate({'top': '0px'}, 700);
        return false;
});

$(window).click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#header').animate({'top': '-100px'}, 700);

    $('#menu-button').css({
       left: '5px'
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/juzv78rw/)

**UPDATE**

To prevent the word "menu" from showing up right away you can add a callback function to your `.animate` which will run after the header is done with its animation:

```
$('#header').animate({'top': '-100px'}, 700, function(){

    $('#menu-button').css({left: '5px'});

});
```

[**FIDDLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/juzv78rw/1/)

**UPDATE 2**

To prevent the animation from bubbling add `.stop()`

```
$('#header').stop().animate({'top': '0px'}, 700);
```

[**FIDDLE 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/juzv78rw/2/)

Comment: With event.stopPropagation() the links are working, but if i click more then one time on the screen the menu employs more than 800 milliseconds to appear , there is a way to limit the closing function of the menu with a single click?

Comment: @FeliceCaricati what do you mean? Are you talking about when you close the menu the word "menu" shows up immediately?

Comment: Sorry , I was unclear , using " event.stopPropagation " the links work , but if I click more than once on the page the #header then takes a long time to appear after clicking on the button #menu-button , I think it is because each click activates the animation that moves the #header of 100 pixels off the screen , so if I click 10 times the # header Has -1000px margin.

Comment: @FeliceCaricati Ok I think I understand, I updated my answer, when you call `top: -100px` thats only animating to a position, its not adding up unless you were to call `top`:`-=100`+`px`, then it would keep adding 100. In this case the animation was just being triggered over and over and was backed up in the queue

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$(window).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#header').animate({'top': '-100px'}, 700);


        $('#menu-button').css({
            left: '5px'
        });
    return false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#menu-button').click(function() {
     $('#menu-button').css('left', '-130px');
     $('#header').animate({'top': '0px'}, 700);
    return false;
});
$(window).click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#header').animate({'top': '-100px'}, 700);
    $('#menu-button').css({
        left: '5px'
    });
});
```

```css
#header{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: -100px;
left: 0;
background-color: green;
z-index: 10;
}

#menu-button{
background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html" title="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html" title="">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html" title="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- header ends here -->
        <button id="menu-button">Menu</button>
```